# Label printing: how can I only combine people with relationship

Tags: civimail

There is an option to combine people at one address to get just one printed label, but this is no good for us as we have congregation members living in the same old person's home who should all get an individual mailing. What we really want is only to get combined labels when the members are linked by a relationship. Is there any way of adjusting the mailing label printer to do this without artificially messing around with the mailing addresses to avoid duplicates for the old person's home?

Comment: Are you using Household's in your Civi setup?

Comment: We don't really need to use households, since we either have individuals or married couples in our list. So far, the possibility to link the married couples using relationships seemed adequate. What I need is the possibility to merge addresses, but only for persons in a relationship

Answer (score 5):

If you use households and have the spouses, children also have a relationship of member of household or head of household, then the check box "Merge labels for contacts belonging to the same household" will do what you want.

Comment: This means that I have to set up additional households for all married couples, which is over the top in our case

Comment: After thinking about all this and wanting to avoid programming and tedious processes every time we do a mailing (once a month), then perhaps using households will be the path of least resistance... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could create two mailings one for people with a relationship and one for people without.

Use the relationship report to find all the people with relationships.  Add them to a group.

Create another group with all the people in the congregation.

Then use the Search => Custom Search => Include / Exclude Contacts in a Group / Tag.  You would include the group with all the people and exclude the ones with relationship. This will give you a list of congregation members who don't have a relationship.  Create mailing labels for them without checking any boxes.

Then pull up the group of people with relationships and create labels for them checking combine addresses.

The downsides of this approach is every time you do a mailing you'll have to empty the groups and repopulate them.

Comment: This approach would work, but means that the secretary has to remember to recreate the groups each time, which is rather tedious and prone to error, so not really a good solution, I'm afraid

Comment: If you only have one or two old folks home, you could create a group, possible a smart group, for the people in the home.  Then print the mailing labels for everyone (manually remove the one for the old folks home) and then print labels for the group with the people in the home.

Comment: You might be able to create a smart group for everyone minus the people with the old folks home address so it's more automatic.

You could also explore using a tag for the people in the home.  You can easily tag them by searching on address and selecting the option for assign tag.  Then print by tags or minus tags.

Comment: After I wrote the comments above I thought of another way that will be more automatic.  This assumes you don't have that many different old folks homes:

1.  Use advance query and search for the address of the old folks home
2.  Create a smart group for them, old-folks-home
3.  Create a smart group for everyone
4.  Do the custom exclude search, search for everyone minus the old-folks-home.
5.  Create a smart group from this search, everyone-minus-old
6.  Now do two mailings one for everyone-minus-old using combine and one for old-folks-home not using combine.

Comment: @Paul-Tahoe, you are able to edit your answer to improve it or provide a second answer.  Either option would be better than including your six steps as a comment

Comment: I tried to search for people with a specific relationship and the query failed with the message "DB Error: no such field", which was rather annoying. I have customised the relationship list to use German names, so perhaps that broke something?

Comment: What version are you on?